# How to get the shot date of the downloaded UIImage(exif) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, exif

How to fetch the exif metadata of the UIImage downloaded from the Internet? I have googled a long time but none of them included the exif key in the dictionary.Anyone knows how to get it in iOS8?

Comment: Did you check this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/EXIF_Dictionary_Keys. `kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal` looks pretty promising to me.